# Why use commands? Events seem to fit

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, nservicebus, azure-eventgrid

**Is there a specific situation where sending an event is not good enough and we must send a command?**

For example there's a system (A) that receives and order + orderlines. System A validates the order. If the order is valid, then another system (B) needs to do much more processing. We can send a command from A to B (please handle order command) or we can send an event from A to B (order is accepted event).

It looks like an event fits fine here. And if we later on need System C to do something with the accepted order we can let it listen to the event. I'm not sure if I miss something if I use events instead of commands.

Comment: Do you have a definition of command?

Comment: Maybe this can be used as a defiition: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CommandMessage.html

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Commands are data rich and meant for internal service/components communications where there is high coupling, Events are light in data (usually only Ids) and meant to be used for cross-boundary communications where there is a loose coupling between the publisher and the subscriber.

More info here: https://particular.net/blog/putting-your-events-on-a-diet